# Is it permissible to marry a non-religious Jewish women?

Tags: women, marriage

Is it permissible to marry a non-religious Jewish women?

How it is possible or how is it not-possible?

Comment: What do you mean is it possible? Do you mean is it permissible under Jewish law?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judaism requires Jews to marry other Jews. But, like many laws, not everyone keeps this.

A *religiously-observant* Jewish man is allowed to marry a *non-religiously-observant* Jewish woman, but they will have to have some serious conversations -- for instance, if she doesn't keep kosher but he does, will the kitchen be kosher?

A non-observant Jewish man could certainly marry a non-observant Jewish woman. This one's relatively straightforward.

As for a non-Jewish man: Judaism prohibits intermarriage. Now sadly, there are plenty of non-observant Jewish women who marry non-Jewish men anyhow. Usually there will be conversations about how they will affiliate, and especially with which faith to raise the kids. (Jewish law views the children of a Jewish mother as always Jewish.) In some situations the husband may convert -- if he's sincere about it, great. Sometimes he may feel pressured to do a quickie conversion that he doesn't really believe in, which isn't ideal from the standpoint of Jewish law nor their relationship.

People are complicated!

Lastly, if the man is a Kohen (i.e. his ancestors were priests in the Temple), he's only allowed to marry a born-Jewish woman who was never divorced (widowed is okay), nor ever had a non-Jewish "boyfriend."